# ¿Como hago que una función sea importada correctamente desde otro archivo Python?

Tags: python, discord.py

Soy bastante nuevo utilizando Python, y por más que busqué no encontraba la solución a la siguiente problemática:

Estaba tratando de importar las variables de la función de otro archivo, el archivo con la función en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
def myfunction():
    number1 = 2
    number2 = 5
```

Ahora, el archivo a importar es de la siguiente forma:

```
from functionarchive import myfunction
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer por ejemplo que la variable "number1" se sume con la variable "number2" en el archivo donde se encuentra el import?

O también, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una de las variables de aquella función sirva como "prefijo" para otra función en el archivo "import"?
Por ejemplo, en discord.py existe bot.run(), donde bot es una variable que se debe definir y run es una función. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los datos de "bot" se alojen en la función de otro archivo?

Saludos.

Comment: Imposible, las variables de crean y destruyen dentro de la función (a menos que sean globales) te recomiendo repensar tu estructura y plantear mejor lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón por la que no puedes hacer que las variables `number1` y `number2` se sumen en el archivo donde se encuentra el import es debido a que estas variables son locales de la función `myFunction()`, es decir, solo existen dentro de esa función. Para que puedas usarlas debes de declarlas globalmente en el archivo *functionarchive*.
Respecto a tu segunda pregunta, de la cual considero deriva tu confusión, ese tipo de acciones es posible mediante la creación de clases. Te doy un ejemplo:

```
class Numeros:
  def __init__(self, numero1, numero2):
    self.numero1 = numero1
    self.numero2 = numero2

  def get_numero1(self):
    return self.numero1

  def get_numero2(self):
    return self.numero2
  
  def sumar_numeros(self):
      return self.numero1+self.numero2;
```

El anterior código presente crea una clase llamada *Numeros*, esta solo guarda dos *atributos*, que los puedes entender como variables: `numero1` y `numero2`. Consigo esta clase también se crean las funciones `getNumero1()`, `getNumero2()` y `sumarNumeros()`.
Importando esta clase a nuestro *main.py*, creamos la variables nums que se encargará de guardar un objeto del tipo *Numeros*, cuyas "variables" serán 5 y 3:

```
from functionararchive import Numeros
nums = Numeros(5,3)
```

Y es a partir de esta variable sobre la cual podemos realizar las funciones anteriormente definidas, obteniendo el comportamiento que tu observas en *discord.py*:

```
print(nums.get_numero1()) #->5
print(nums.get_numero2()) #->3
print(nums.sumar_numeros()) #->8
```

En caso de que deseas ahondar mas en este tema, te recomiendo buscar "Programación orientada a objetos en python". Es a partir de este paradigma que puedes obtener el comportamiento que preguntabas :)